# Does the ConnectionPool from SqlJocky require a close

Tags: mysql, heroku, dart

I'm creating a back-end server application in Dart which is using a MySQL database to store data. To make the SQL call I'm using the ConnectionPool from SqlJocky.

What I do when the app starts:

1. Create a singleton which store the ConnectionPool
2. Execute multiple queries with prepareExecute and query

Locally this approach is working fine. Now I pushed a development version to Heroku and I'm getting connection issues after a few minutes.

So I wonder, do I need to close/release a single connection from the pool I use to execute a query? Or is the connection after the query placed again in the pool and free for use?

The abstract base class for all the MySQL stores:

```
abstract class MySQLStore {

  MySQLStore(ConnectionPool connectionPool) {
    this._connectionPool = connectionPool;
  }

  ConnectionPool get connectionPool => this._connectionPool;
  ConnectionPool _connectionPool;
}
```

A concrete implementation for the method getAll:

```
Future<List<T>> getAll() async {
  Completer completer = new Completer();

  connectionPool.query("SELECT id, name, description FROM role").then((result) {
    return result.toList();
  }).then((rows) {
    completer.complete(this._processRows(rows));
  }).catchError((error) {
    // TODO: Better error handling.
    print(error);
    completer.complete(null);
  });

  return completer.future;
}
```

The error I get:

> SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = ...

Comment: I didn't use this for a long time but I would assume you need to close it. How could SqlJocky know when to reuse a connection when it is not closed.

Comment: There is a close call on the connection pool, but this will close all connections: http://jamesots.github.io/sqljocky/docs/sqljocky/ConnectionPool.html.

Comment: Might be just a convenience method for example when you leave the application to ensure all resources are released. Lets hope someone with more in-depth knowledge adds an answer ;-)

Comment: I am using the call prepareExecute which does return a result. I noticed there is also a prepare call which returns a Query object with a close method. But I would presume prepareExecute would close it after execute.

Comment: In you comment you write you use `prepareExecute` but your example uses `query`

Comment: I also got a response from Heroku "Heroku's networking enforces an idle timeout of 60-90 seconds to prevent runaway processes. If you're using persistent connections in your application, make sure that you're sending a keep-alive at, say, 55 seconds to prevent your open connection from being dropped by the server." I also found that the MySQL connection string as defined in the Heroku vars has the reconnect option set to true. I did not find a reconnect option inside the sqljocky code?

Comment: Might be worth a bug report/feature request in the [sqljocky GitHub](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues) repo. Your question might also be related to https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues/54. The error message is similar to https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues/51 (but looks like a different issue)

Comment: Added some comments to issue #54 https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues/54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some feedback from Heroku I managed to resolve this problem by implementing a timer task that does every 50 seconds a basic MySQL call.

The response from Heroku:

> Heroku's networking enforces an idle timeout of 60-90 seconds to prevent runaway processes. If you're using persistent connections in your application, make sure that you're sending a keep-alive at, say, 55 seconds to prevent your open connection from being dropped by the server.

The work around code:

```
const duration = const Duration(seconds: 50);

new Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t) {
  // Do a simple MySQL call with on the connection pool.
  this.connectionPool.execute('SELECT id from role');
  print('*** Keep alive triggered for MySQL heroku ***');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't fully answer your question but I think you could simplify your code like:

```
Future<List<T>> getAll() async {
  try {
    var result = await connectionPool.query(
        "SELECT id, name, description FROM role");
    return this._processRows(await result.toList());
  } catch(error) {
    // TODO: Better error handling.
    print(error);
    return null;
  } 
}
```

I'm sure here is no need to close a connection with `query`. I don't know about `prepareExecute` though.
According to a comment in the SqlJocky code it can take quite some time for a connection to be released by the database server.
Maybe you need to increase the connection pool size (default 5) so you don't run out of connections while `ConnectionPool` is waiting for connections to be released.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the better code, my newer code uses the approach with await. The Connectionpool is not the issue, because I restarted the server instance, do one call, wait 10 minutes and then do the call again which will fail. It must be something "Heroku related"...

Comment: Another remark regarding the connection pool. I also use the Apache Benchmark tool to stress test the server. Locally this can easily handle 1000 requests with 50 simultaneously.